# How to edit a custom bone display mesh whose object has been deleted

Tags: objects, armature, bones, data-blocks

I did the following:

1. Add a `Circle` named "BoneIcon"
2. Assign `Circle` as the "Custom Object" of several bones
3. Delete the `Circle` object

Now I'd like to edit that `Circle` mesh and have the changes applied to all the bones I assigned it to. "BoneIcon" is no longer in the "View Layer" panel, but both the object and the mesh are visible in the "Blender File" panel (though the object is shown in dimmed text).

Is there any way to restore the object so I can edit it, or create a new object so I can edit the original mesh data?

[image: BoneIcon in BlenderFile]

Comment: I realized I can click and drag the `BoneIcon` object from the "Blender File" panel into the 3D view, but that creates an object with a copy of the Mesh, not a link to the original Mesh.

Answer (score 0):

Drag-and-drop the `BoneIcon` object from the "Blender File" panel into a collection in the "View Layer" panel, and it will appear in the 3D editor.